# React Value is undefined on Button Click [used for passing state up]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components, state

**Child Class Below**

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handlePageChange(e) {
    this.props.handlePageChange(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);  <----- This is undefined
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="branding">
          <img src=#### alt="####### logo"></img>
          <h2>#######</h2>
          <span>Web Portal</span>
        </div>
        <div className="navlinks">
          <span>MENU</span>
          <div className="nav-boxes">
            <button onClick={this.handlePageChange} value="Overview">
              <HomeIcon style={{ fill: "#5c66bd" }} />
              <span>Overview</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="nav-boxes">
            <button onClick={this.handlePageChange} value="Knowledge">
              <SchoolIcon style={{ fill: "#4d7d48" }} />
              <span>Knowledge Base</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="nav-boxes">
            <button onClick={this.handlePageChange} value="Health">
              <FavoriteIcon style={{ fill: "#63182a" }} />
              <span>Health</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="nav-boxes">
            <button onClick={this.handlePageChange} value="Support">
              <ContactSupportIcon style={{ fill: "#5c66bd" }} />
              <span>Live Support</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="nav-boxes">
            <button onClick={this.handlePageChange} value="Documents">
              <ArticleIcon style={{ fill: "#8a7f1c" }} />
              <span>Documents</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <NavLogin />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is my Navigation, i want the "current page" to be changed, passing the state
upward, where it can then be passed down to the content to show the correct page.

I've added a console.log for the HandlePageChange function and see that my e.target.value
is undefined. I cant see why as its being called when i click on the Nav buttons

**Parent Class if needed and its something obvious**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { currpage: "Overview" };
  }

  handlePageChange(newPage) {
    this.setState({ currpage: newPage });
  }

  render() {
    const { currpage } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        <Navbar handlePageChange={this.handlePageChange} currpage={currpage} />
        <Content
          handlePageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          username={"#####"}
          currpage={currpage}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just cant see why my e.target.value is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` is the most nested element on anywhere that you have clicked. since you have nested an `span` inside the `button`, in the callback `e.target` is actually the span, which doesn't have a `value`.

Use `e.currentTarget` instead, which contains `value`. the `currentTarget` property on an event refers to the element with the event handler (`Button`).

```
  handlePageChange(e) {
this.props.handlePageChange(e.currentTarget.value);
console.log(e.currentTarget.value);   
 }
```